# Httppost cannot find method setConfig android

Tags: android, apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to write an `HttpPost` request using `httpclient-4.5.5`.
I'm getting an `error` in the line `httpPost.setConfig(requestConfig);`

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(mEntityBuilder.build());

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)
                .setConnectTimeout(timeout).setSocketTimeout(timeout)
                .build();
        httpPost.setConfig(requestConfig);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

> The error is - Error:(97, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setConfig(RequestConfig)

I looked the the HttpPost class, it extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase which in turn extends HttpRequestBase which has the public method setConfig.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: I have added the line android {useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'} in the app gradle file. And I have added the httpclient-4.5.5 jar module to my android project.

Answer (score -1):

*Remove* `{useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}` in gradle file
if you *add* `{useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}` in gradle file. Android studio will use the `"org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost"` in *Android SDK*. But it has no methods about *setConfig()*. Add `"httpclient.jar"` in your project.